# Why is Poland the most homophobic country in the EU?

Tags: lgbt+, poland

According to [rainbow-europe.org](https://rainbow-europe.org/) Poland has the lowest percentage of achieved LGBTI human rights. I am trying to find the reasons for this by asking the following questions:

- Why does homophobia exist in Poland?
- What was the process of its development?
- What was the historical/political background accompanying it?

The research that I found only measured the current status of it without analysing the "genealogy" or "anatomy" of homophobia in Poland. Can you think of any sources where I can find information on it? Do you think that the way the questions are put would lead to an answer to the low percentage?

Answer (score 9):

The most practiced [religion in Poland](https://stat.gov.pl/en/infographics-and-widgets/infographics/infographic-religiousness-of-polish-inhabitiants,4,1.html) was Roman Catholicism, whose followers comprised the 92.8% of the population. Such a high religious population of a religion that according to their bible views homosexuality as a sin... well that's almost self explanatory on why it is hostile towards the LGBT+.

But it should be mentioned that Poland itself is politically divided through the middle. During the 2007 elections the **Civic Platform**  were dominant in the western, more industrialized, regions (orange) while in the East (blue) **Law and Justice** were dominant. Both are rightwing leaning Christian  parties with one of the differences being that Law and Justice is " far right"  conservative while Civic Platform adopted more liberal/non-religious stances over the years.

But although the Civic Platform has become more open towards the LGBT+ they have been losing power in recent years to the Law And Justice party. But this is often attributed to the Law And Justice Party anti EU stance. So people who might be personally open towards the LGBT might vote for the anti-LGBT party due to their opposition towards the EU being more important to them then LGBT+ rights. Making the government seem more hostile towards it then the actual people are.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Countries like Malta, Lithuania, Portugal, Croatia, Ireland have similar percentage of Roman Catholics (according to "Discrimination in the EU in 2015", Special Eurobarometer) and they have much or slightly higher percentage of achieved LGBTI human rights (89%, 23%, 66%, 46% and 52% accordingly). Are these instances of Roman Catholicism different?

Comment: @apex39 Yes, because of the Pope. Period from '45 to '89 is considered a Soviet occupation and in popular consciousness church and John Paul II were instrumental in regaining independence. Out of countries you listed, Lithuania should have most similar experience, except pope wasn't Lithuanian. JP2 "our pope" is revered to both ridiculous and disgusting degree, latter part because in best religious traditions, this reverence relies on empty platitudes, non-gestures and is used as justification for varying degrees of awful behaviour.

Comment: @apex39 personally I think it's tied to the EU. The EU is highly liberal and certain countries/political parties change their policies to appease the EU. For Example one of my countries largest political parties highly disagrees with how the EU handles certain things (sometimes in direct contradiction with their election points) but when it comes to the point they fold in favor of the EU. But the politicians in Poland seem to be more steadfast in their defiance against the EU.